# Как нормально сделать фон как на этом скриншоте?

Tags: css

Понимаю что вопрос тупой и наверное слишком простой но все же Как мне адекватно написать фон как на этом скрине [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А то я что-то пытаюсь пытаюсь а оно постоянно что-то не так
Короче помогите

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Прописать в css "background: #color" для body и всем div'ам, из которых состоит шаблон страницы.

Answer (score 0):

фон можно взять еще выше, полностью залить цветом:

```css
main{
background:#D3D3D3;
}
```

Или же поставить тег background:color; на тот блок который нужно. Скорее всего там header тогда, в него пишется background.